# database name variable in php function

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I would like to make php Function where I will send database name (I use MSSQL 2008):

```
function get_query($database)
(
    $query = ";WITH [cteRows] AS
    (
        SELECT  [nazwa],
                [wartosc],
                [czas],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [czas]) AS [RowNumber]
        FROM ('$database')
        WHERE [nazwa] = 'coldbox7/WymianaDanychDB/Hydraulic' 
        AND [czas] >= '2016-07-14 22:00:00.000' 
        AND [czas] <= '2016-07-14 22:30:00.000'
    )";
return $query;
)
$database1 = '[test].[dbo].[coldbox7]';
$query1 = get_query($database1);
```

I have errors, could you tell me how should I send database name to query?

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing here.. You are returning `$query` but I don't see the variable being assigned any value.. Where are you writing this function?

Comment: Query strings are....strings. You are not returning a string.

Comment: when I make FROM [test].[dbo].[coldbox7] is all ok, the question is how to send [test].[dbo].[coldbox7] to function